# How do I demonstrate Orphan process through system("ps -l") command?

Tags: operating-system

I need to demonstrate that the child process has become orphan process when its parent has terminated . But as soon as the parent terminates , the child is adopted by the root process . So how do I demonstrate it to be an orphan ?

Answer (score 0):

You can show it like this :

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  if (fork()==0){
    sleep(2);
    printf("\nHello from Child!\n");
  }
  else{
    //sleep(1);
    printf("Hello from Parent!\n");
  }
  system("ps -l");
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Orphan Process Demonstration]
Here, In `Hello from Parent!` the process `a.out` with **PID 4854** creates a child with **PID 4855** (3rd line). And this child process in `Hello from Child!` is owned by process with **PID 1412** (rather than process with **PID 4854** (2nd line)). So the child process is adopted by the process with **PID 1412**.